# dig command does not show A records

Tags: dns, mdns, fortigate

I brought up a DNS server on a Fortigate 60D.
However, instead of `dig` giving me all the A records I defined (about 80 of them), all I see is this (note the lack of any lines of the form
`local.            172719  IN      A       192.168.1.97`):

```
$ dig local all

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-72.el7 <<>> local all
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 15919
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;local.                         IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       1293    IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019012302 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.99#53(192.168.1.99)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 23 13:52:42 PST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 26634
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;all.                           IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       3600    IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019012302 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.99#53(192.168.1.99)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 23 13:52:42 PST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

Where I expected to something similar to:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
local.            86400  IN      NS      dns.local.    
local.            86400  IN      A       192.168.1.97
local.            86400  IN      A       192.168.1.98
```

Can you suggest a way to make dig display the A records?

Comment: Does your DNS software use syntax similar to a Bind9 zonefile? If so, did you update the serial?  Did you reload the service after the data change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a workaround to get *A records*, but it's better than nothing:

```
(echo "diag test app dnsproxy 8"; echo "exit") | ssh -tt <user>@<Fortigate IP>
```

The above will display all *A records* on the shell line.

Answer (score 1):

```
 dig local A
```

This will request only A records for the domain "local".   I normally specify a server -

```
dig @server.name domain.name A
```

Comment: As you can see in the example I gave in the OP, the replay for `dig local all` does not include any A records. When I do `dig local A` or `dig @192.168.1.99 local A`, I get the same results as when I do `dig local all`, namely - no A records are displayed, besides `;; QUESTION SECTION:
;local.                         IN      A`.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be reasonable to conclude that the A records have not been loaded for the zone?

Comment: However, I can see the A records with the command `dia test application dnsprox 8` on the Fortigate 60D, not to mention that name resolution works in my LAN machines.